# Error with query in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

My SQLLite query is not working properly. See below:

```
 UUID i=UUID.randomUUID();
        String Beregero ="INSERT INTO 
 contacts(id,uuid,name,phone,email,street,city,state,zip) " +
          " VALUES(3,"+"'"+i.toString()+"'"+",'Patrice 
 Beregeron','978-555-1212','pBeregero@BostonBruins.com'," +
          "'1 causeway street','Boston','Mass','01236');";
 db.execSQL(Beregero);
```

I am receiving  the following error in my log:

```
(table contacts has no column named uuid (code 1): , while 
compiling: INSERT INTO contacts(id,uuid,name,phone,email,
street,city,state,zip)  VALUES(3,'12ee5bbf-dabb-4d95-bfe7-6e6f14702add',
'Patrice Beregeron','978-555-1212','pBeregero@BostonBruins.com',
'1 causeway street','Boston','Mass','01236');)
#################################################################
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception says it all, your table has no column name uuid created. So uninstall the app, then run it again. This error occurs only if the column is not generated.

Answer (score 0):

You have not added the column "`uuid`" in the create table "`contacts`" query like this :

```
String createTableContacts = "create table contacts ( ' uuid text ')";
```

Comment: @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String  CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE " + ContactDbSchema.ContactTable.NAME + "(" +
                ContactDbSchema.ContactTable.Cols.ID +"  integer primary key , " +
                ContactDbSchema.ContactTable.Cols.UUIDD+"TEXT, "+

Comment: ok you need to give space before and after declaring the dataType for uuid like :
 ContactDbSchema.ContactTable.Cols.UUIDD+" TEXT,  "

Comment: @HiteshSarsava The code in your answer obviously is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: @HiteshSarsava I neither know Java nor SQLite, so I can't show the correct code, but I am absolutely sure that in this case at least the quotes must match (i.e. there must be an even number of quotes and not an odd one as in your answer).

Answer (score 0):

The error message in you log clearly states the problem. The `contacts` table does not have a column `uuid`. You now could do the following:

- Check if you have got right lower case vs. upper case. The column in question might be `UUID` instead of `uuid` (I don't know SQLite, but case matters in many database systems).
- If the column really is not in the table yet, then add it (either by code or by hand). Read SQLite's documentation to learn how to that (I can't help you here because I don't know SQLite).

Uninstalling and re-installing the app would help *only* if the app would generate the database upon installing or during the first run. Since we don't know anything about the app, this might or might not be the case.